# How to check if a queue is empty when I need to use two stacks to form a queue?

Tags: python-3.x, stack, queue

My homework needs to use two stacks to create a queue. Now my queue can do what the question is asking but it's giving me an error when the test case use while loop to check if queue is empty.

'''

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.in_stack = Stack()#stack is provided for us
        self.out_stack = Stack()#stack is provided for us
    def is_empty(self):#I think this causes the error 
        if self.called1 == False:
            return True
    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.called1 = True
        self.in_stack.push(item)
    def dequeue(self):
        self.called = True
        while not self.in_stack.is_empty():
            self.out_stack.push(self.in_stack.pop())
        return self.out_stack.pop()
    def size(self):
        if self.called == True:
            return self.out_stack.size()
        else:
            return self.in_stack.size()
'''
'''
#test case
q = Queue()
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)
q.enqueue(4)
while not q.is_empty():
  print(q.dequeue())
'''
'''
#test result
1#correct
2#correct
3#correct
4#correct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\12.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(q.dequeue())
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\12.py", line 36, in dequeue
    return self.out_stack.pop()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\12.py", line 15, in pop
    return self.list.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list#don't know why it's still pop when the stack is empty
>>> 
'''
```

Comment: You never initialized `self.called` and `self.called1` in the constructor. What are the initial values of those variables?

Comment: These two are used to check if the test case call enqueue or dequeue.

Comment: So, please initialize them. `if self.called1 == False` fails if `self.called1` has never been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the purpose of the exercise is very dubious (a convoluted way to abuse the data structures) your have to remember the difference between the stack and the queue.  A queue is a first in first out structure, while the stack is first on last out.

If you pop all items from one stack and push them in another you are doing a double inversion. And they FILO stacks can produce FIFO behavior like a queue. But...

You cannot push anything in the second stack if you started consuming the items until it is empty.

So keep the in stack for incoming elements. Then once you have a dequeue pop from the second stack until it is empty and then and only then your transfer the elements from stack 1 to stack 2...

```
def _move_stack(self):
     while not self.in_stack.is_empty():
```

self.out_stack.push(self.in_stack.pop())

```
def dequeue(self):

    If out_stack.is_empty():
        self._move_stack()


    return self.out_stack.pop()
```

Comment: To keep the in stack for incoming elements, should I not use the while loop?

Comment: Let's say you have incoming 3 elements : a b c. If you push all of them in the first stack , and consume by popping, then you will have them in reverted order. To info the reversion you use another stack to push all of them inside and start popping from it. So internally you will have : push a-s1, push b, s-1, push c, s1. Then when you are done with insertions you can use the other stack . However,  if while consuming you try to enwueue another element. It will come soon the top of the second stack and break the order. Example. Input a,b,c ,  dequeue a, enqueue d, dequeue d.

Comment: To avoid such change of order you cannot push to the second stack unless it is empty.